# HTML5 drag and drop multiple images from one canvas to another canvas

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, drag-and-drop

Im new to HTML5 and jquery(2 weeks) and i need to create a drag and drop multiple images from one canvas to another canvas using jquery and html5 and also must be able to resize the images(my boss has given me this assignment) , i have been trying for almost 3 to 4 days now to get it right but been unsuccessful till now.please help me out with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you've tried so far, but after a quick google search this tutorial should be a good start:

http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape

UPDATE:
The following existing questions might help:

- [How to Copy Contents of One Canvas to Another Canvas Locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4405336/how-to-copy-contents-of-one-canvas-to-another-canvas-locally)
- [How to drag and drop from one HTML5 canvas to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599801/how-to-drag-and-drop-from-one-html5-canvas-to-another)
- [HTML5 Canvas + select / drag-and-drop features in a JS lib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2801416/html5-canvas-select-drag-and-drop-features-in-a-js-lib)

Comment: Thanks for the link im gonna go through that.but my main problem has been in copying an image from one canvas to another through drag and drop method.

Comment: @Kaushik, see the links to existing SO questions that ask similar questions

Comment: thanks for the links ,i somehow figuredout a way to drag and drop,but now i have no idea on how to resize or move the image,[link](http://www.mediafire.com/?r03gr3e7beq12e8) ,please do look at this link ive uploaded my file,maybe if you give a look,u can help me out.

Comment: i tried using canvas instead of div in my program but the image was not visible.